# local development of microservices, methods and tools to work efficiently

Tags: docker-compose, microservices, docker-swarm, development-environment, skaffold

I work with teams members to develop a microservices architecture but I have a problem with the way to work. Indeed, I have too many microservices and when I run them during my development, it consumes too memory even with a good workstation. So I use docker compose to build and execute my MSA but it takes a long time. One often hears about how technically build an MSA but never about the way to work efficiently to build it. How do you do in this case ? How do you work ? Do you use tools or any others to improve and facilitate your developments. I've heard about skaffold but I don't see what the difference is with docker compose or with a simple ci/cd in a cluster env for example. Feel free to give tips and your opinion. Thanks

Comment: Good question but I bet this question will be closed pretty soon because it does not fit the scope of stackoverflow :/

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I've had a fair amount of experience with microservices and local development and here's been some approaches I've seen:

1. Run all the things locally on docker or k8. If using k8, then a tool like skaffolding can make it easier to run and debug a service locally in the IDE but put it into your local k8 so that it can communicate with other k8 services. It works OK but running more than 4 or 5 full services locally in k8 or docker requires dedicating a substantial amount of CPU and memory.
2. Build mock versions of all your services. Use those locally and for integration tests. The mock services are intentionally much simpler and therefore easier to run lots of them locally. Obvious downside is that you have to build mock version of every service, and you can easily miss bugs that are caused by mock services not behaving like the real service. Record/replay tools like Hoveryfly can help in building mock services.
3. Give every developer their own Cloud environment. Run most services in the cloud but use a tool like [Telepresence](https://telepresence.io) to swap locally running services in and out of the cloud cluster. This eliminates the problem of running too many services on a single machine but can be spendy to maintain separate cloud sandboxes for each developer. You also need a DevOps resource to help developers when their cloud sandbox gets out of whack.
4. Eliminate unnecessary microservice complexity and consolidate all your services into 1 or 2 monoliths. Enjoy being able to run everything locally as a single service. Accept the fact that a microservice architecture is overkill for most companies. Too many people choose a microservice architecture upfront before their needs demand it. Or they do it out of fear that they will need it in the future. Inevitably this leads to guessing how they should decompose the system into many microservices, and getting the boundaries and contracts wrong, which makes it just as hard or harder to fix in the future compared to a monolith. And they incur the costs of microservices years before they need to. Microservices make everything more costly and painful, from local development to deployment. For companies like Netflix and Amazon, it's necessary. For most of us, it's not.

I prefer option 4 if at all possible. Otherwise option 2 or 3 in that order. Option 1 should be avoided in my opinion but it is probably the option everyone tries first.

Comment: Wow that is exactly how I would answer. I strongly agree with point 4 with 6 years of microservices experience.

Comment: I think `4` makes a lot of sense, but as the solution grows you will have to deal increased complexity in CI and tooling - you won't want to run thousands of unit/integration (or UI) tests for every single commit. So that's a downside of the monolith approach.

Comment: Follow up on `4` (that being the most popular and of least resistance): How do you share code with third-party (contract) developers without divulging (secret) business logic that will be inevitably shared in a monolithic architecture?

Comment: @analytical_prat Make the 3rd-party contract developers sign an NDA.

Answer (score 1):

I would say create a staging environment which will have all services running. This staging environment will specifically be curated for development. E.g. if it's deployed using k8s then you expose some ports using nodeport service if you need them for your specific microservice. And have a DevOps pipeline to always keep this environment up to date with the code.

This environment should always be built from master branch. If you have single repo for app or repo per service, it's fair assumption that the will always have most recent code when you create your dev/feature branch.

Then when you want to develop a feature or fix a bug you checkout your microservice. And if you are following the microservice pattern appropriately, that single microservice should be an executable and have it's own docker file and should be debuggable from your local IDE. Many enterprises follow this pattern, and enforce at the organization level that the master branch is always production ready and high quality.

Let's say, you discover a bug in some other microservice running in k8s cluster. You will very likely get tempted to find a way to debug that remote microservice. However, that should be written as a bug for the team that owns the microservice. If your team owns it then you fix it and then start working on your feature. If you really think you need to debug multiple microservices, then I think you have real tight coupling between the services or you don't really need the microservice architecture.

Answer (score 0):

In GKE and assuming you have a private cluster. You can utilize port forwarding while hooked up to the GKE environment through the CLI. Create a script that forwards your local ports to the GKE environment. I believe on the services tab in your cluster is where you will find the "port-forwarding" button that will give you the CMD command. This way you can work on one microservice with all of its traffic being routed to the actual DEV cluster. This prevents you from having to run multiple projects at the same time.