# Microservice local development guidance

Tags: visual-studio, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, microservices

I'm looking for some guidance on an approach to developing microservices locally.  I realise that there will be many different approaches, but I'm just looking for some examples and then I can decide which approach might be suit my situation.

I'm currently looking at moving a monolithic system to a microservice system.  I'm using Docker, and Docker Compose, to 'containerize' each service (via Visual Studio 2019) and I've put each service into their own Solution (.sln) and their own Git repository (Azure Repos).  I'm predicting that there will be many times where I need to work on two or more services at the same time (e.g. I need Service A to publish an event to Service B, and I need to update Service B to handle this new event).

My question is, what approaches has anyone used to handle a scenario like this ... where you need to work on both Service A and Service B at the same time, but might also need Service C and Service D to be running as well?  Can/should I use multiple Docker Compose files to handle this situation?  Would it be better to use local Kubernetes (via Docker Desktop) for this scenario?  Should I just run a script that downloads and runs all my service images and then work on the services in question?

If someone is able to share their experience, or point me to some documentation that talks about this, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64251489/local-development-of-microservices-methods-and-tools-to-work-efficiently

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best solution is the one that helps you have what you need in the fastest possible way. And sometimes the best solution is the one you already know.

Basically you need the services running. What I do when I need only a few services is to start and configure them by hand (each developer from the team uses his own setup). This is an annoying process sometimes but it needs to be done. Using a docker-compose won't really help because things change with time. Of course you can have a docker-compose file for every possible config as long as you can keep track of them.

One other thing that I used is to have the entire application deployed in an dev/alpha environment and from my local I am connecting to the services I need. This reduces the memory used on the local system and you will have access to all other services just by pointing at them with an URL. This method may be helpful when you need to start more than, let's say, 5 services.

I am mixing these two methods in order to obtain a faster result.

Your approach seems fine to me. Maybe you can do a few tweaks to improve it but this really depends on what you have locally.

Another things that I used to do, when an dev/alpha environment was not at my disposal, was to deploy all the services into a local Kubernetes single node cluster on a separate machine (like a laptop or raspberry pi, sometimes both). This helps you avoiding the costs of having your own cluster in the cloud and the application config is always at hand (for example you do not need authentication). I am talking here about tens of services.

At some point, if you are going to end up with that many services then you will need to move to a dev environment in cloud since your local memory won't be enough.

Comment: You make a good point ... I am trying to find that balance between choosing the fastest solution and the solution that will work best long term.  From best I can see, there is not really one elegant solution.  I'm thinking there will be no way around running scripts or multiple processes to get it all working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure absolutely every last thing that could refer to a host name is configurable as an environment variable.  If one service calls another, its host name or URL is an environment variable; if something uses a database, the database location is an environment variable; and so on.  These environment variables should generally default to things that will be useful in a developer setup, and you can override them at deploy time.

If you do that, then you can launch a small number of services in your development environment

```
# Starts a, b, c, d on ports 8001, 8002, 8003, 8004
docker-compose up -d
# C_URL defaults to http://localhost:8003, etc.
PORT=7001 B_URL=http://localhost:7002 ./service_a.sh
PORT=7002 ./service_b.sh
curl -XPOST http://localhost:7001/invoke-b
```

Do make sure you have solid unit tests, that are actually unit tests.  Service A's tests should not depend on a database, service B, or anything else.  You'll obviously only get so far with testing the system this way and you'll also need integration tests, but if you can run

```
./a_tests.sh
```

without starting anything else and cover 80% of your code, your tests will get run and your business logic will get tested; if running tests at all requires a working end-to-end setup they won't get run and things will fail in your CI environment.

> I need Service A to publish an event to Service B...

Using a dedicated message broker can help this case.  I'm familiar with RabbitMQ as an open-source option, but there are other choices.  This breaks the dependency chain: A needs the message broker so it can send the message there, but doesn't specifically depend on B running; B needs the message broker and its input message but not necessarily the producer.  If most inter-service communication happens only via the message broker, then services only need themselves and the broker running.

```sh
docker-compose up -d rabbitmq
# https://github.com/jandelgado/rabtap
export RABTAP_AMQPURI=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/
rabtap pub service.a.exchange < a-input.txt
./service_a.sh
rabtap sub service.b.queue
```

> Would it be better to use local Kubernetes (via Docker Desktop) for this scenario? Should I just run a script that downloads and runs all my service images and then work on the services in question?

Having some automation to launch everything, or at least a necessary core of services, is really useful for developers.  Checking out a dozen repositories and running a dozen slightly different start scripts isn't going to scale.  There's an argument for this to be the same as your deployment scripts, which suggests a local Kubernetes (Docker Desktop, minikube, kind) or a shared development cluster, if you're also using Kubernetes in production.  A Docker Compose setup is straightforward, possibly a "launch everything" shell script as well, but these need to be kept up to date as you add services.

If you're using Kubernetes anyways, tools like [Telepresence](https://www.telepresence.io) or [Skaffold](https://skaffold.dev) simplify this specific workflow, and are intended to help with the case of running one service locally and the rest of your environment in the cluster.  If you only have three or four services, and they fit on a single host (even in production, maybe excluding the database), and are comfortable with admins having root permissions over everything, then Kubernetes is going to be more cluster software than you need.